# What does this mean? (Google Maps API)

Tags: google-maps

i've got this error message in the console. can anyone explain why? and the page is running as it should be.

```html
js?key=MyAPIKey&v=3.exp&libraries=places,drawing,geometry:32 InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement_.ab @ js?key=MyAPIKey&v=3.exp&libraries=places,drawing,geometry:32
```

Comment: Without seeing relevant code, no one could really tell 100%

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
InvalidValueError: not an instance of `HTMLInputElement`
```

That's mean you have not set proper id of your html input element.
Google API not able to find that control in your html code. Because of wrong id of input element.

If you using `textarea` then it will not work because google maps autocomplete now supports only `window.HTMLInputElement(input tags)`

For more details Please Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063439/invalidvalueerror-not-an-instance-of-htmlinputelement)

You can also find examples here of [Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)

Comment: I get this with input tags, and no textarea. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error when i use google map autocomplete.

```
InvalidValueError: not an instance of `HTMLInputElement`
```

So i solve this as like .

```
var org = document.getElementById('origin');

 new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(org, options);
```

Answer (score -1):

Add Google `Api CDN` after the callback function

eg.

```
function initMap() {
  //
}
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```