# InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement . How can I fix this issue.?

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a website in which I have used google place search api  service but I am facing an issue i.e. whenever I reload the page, my js stop working and in chrome developer tool I am geting the above error as I asked.

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Show your code? looks like you are not passing required parameter

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063439/invalidvalueerror-not-an-instance-of-htmlinputelement

Comment: Please post your code without posting the code we wont be able to help you out thank you

Comment: From what I know on this, you could be using a text area instead of input field. Google is not supporting autocomplete for text area anymore. If that's not the case, adding the code to your question would make it easy to debug.